# Laravel 3 : best method to redirect (301) old website pages to new pages

Tags: redirect, laravel

I'm trying to figure out a way to redirect the old website's pages to a new website build with laravel 3.

I was thinking on starting to map the related ones in a database and then ... somehow redirected in laravel somehow.

Cheers people

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect the old website with an .htaccess.
Your htaccess file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect oldwebsite.com to new laravelwebsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldwebsite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laravelwebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(oldpage1.html)$ http://laravelwebsite.com/newpage1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(oldpage2)$ http://laravelwebsite.com/newpage2 [R=301,L]
# You can redirect as many pages as you want
```